# Call exe in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I m running a shiny app standalone in my PC. I have a exe application which can be called via command line. I successfully run it via `system` function. 
What I want is to do the same thing in shiny. Is there any way?

Comment: Did you try ? What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `actionButton` and an `observeEvent` that is triggered whenever that `actionButton` is clicked. A simple working example would be:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('run','Run executable!')
)

server<- function(input,output)
{
  observeEvent(input$run,
               {
                 system("cmd.exe", input = "notepad")
               })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!